# Which is the "One-Click Ruby Installer"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a hard time reading open source file download pages like this http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167 . I click the "One-Click Ruby Installer" link on this page http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/getting-started/installation/windows and it takes me there.

I understand most of it like the versions for mac, win and source, version numbers etc. But I just don't know which is the actual one click installer. This is something I've always overlooked with pages like this and I usually just gestimate which I needed. This process is really intimidating.

Which of the many links is the "One-Click Ruby Installer"?
Can you offer any advice on reading pages like these?

Comment: Which is the "One-Click Ruby Installer"?

Comment: what operating system are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually have trouble locating the right download to sometimes, best to just try and find the actual home page and go from there.

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

This is the web page for the Ruby Installer, there's three links right at the top that are for the most recent versions of the installer.

Edit: With regards to the gems+rails you have to install them individually after you install ruby. Depending on the gem you may need to download and install the development kit which is also on the page I linked above. The install for that is simple you just need to copy the files into the folder you installed rails.

Comment: Does this include rails + gems?

Comment: Updated my response about rails and gems

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct link:

http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/71078/rubyinstaller-1.9.1-p378.exe

It was the last link under "Final" in the first list. If you look at the section to the right, you can see the file type and the intended OS. The last link in a section of the list is the newest.